# Data type convert in Mysql or python

Tags: python, mysql, types

I have a .txt file which contains a column of unixtime, like (1322485992.420381000), the number of digits before and after the dot are the same for all data. First I want to import this column into a Mysql table, how should I define the data type?

```
CREATE TABLE videoinfo (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, unixtime char(50))
```

After that, in Python, I need to convert this column into datetime like: 2011-11-28 14:25:23
I use `results`to keep the data fetched from database,then try to convert it into datetime.
But it cannot work, it says `datetime.fromtimestamp requires a float`. But if I use unixtime `float(10,10)` to create the column, data from txt file cannot be written into database.

```
results = cur.fetchall()
for result in results:
    times = datetime.fromtimestamp(result[0])
    cur.execute("ALTER TABLE youtube ADD date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT after unixtime")
    for time in times:
        cur.execute(u'''insert into `date` values (%s)''', time)
```

Can anyone help? Many thanks!!!

-edit-
`for row in cur.fetchall():
        print (row)
        times = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row))`
The print result is `('1322485970.084063000',)`then, the error message is `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number.`
So how can I fetch the pure string value to get rid of `('',)`

-edit-
use row[0] instead...problem solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a `DOUBLE(11,9)` although such a large number may cause problems on 32-bit systems. Consider using a `VARCHAR(21)` if that's an issue.

Also, MySQL simply understands `FROM_UNIXTIME(1322485992.420381000)`.

-edit-

When it says "requires a float", why don't you just use `float(result)` ?

Comment: ok, but I have a column of data needed to be converted, not just a single one

Comment: I used float to define the column, but like I said, the problem is the data in txt file cannot be written into database, but when it's defined as char, it can be written

Comment: Actually I meant using `float()` in Python: `times = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(result[0]))`

Comment: Ok, I tried, got error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): None`

Comment: In that case, as the error says, `result[0]` is `None` which explains why you can't insert it :-)

Comment: `for row in cur.fetchall(): print (row) times = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(row))` The print result is `('1322485970.084063000',)` then, the error message is `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`